# Device driver API match error

Tags: android, device-driver, cyanogenmod

I've installed cyanogenmod on my galaxy 3. 
When developing in Eclipse, most apps seem to work okay.  However,
I've written an app that needs to access the gallery and every time I try to access it the app crashes with this at log cat:

```
02-03 19:05:42.054: D/libEGL(10279): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so

02-03 19:05:42.059: D/libEGL(10279): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so

02-03 19:05:42.059: D/libEGL(10279): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so

02-03 19:05:42.064: E/(10279): Device driver API match

02-03 19:05:42.064: E/(10279): Device driver API version: 23

02-03 19:05:42.064: E/(10279): User space API version: 23 

02-03 19:05:42.064: E/(10279): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct  9         
21:05:57 KST 2013
```

Any idea how I can fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have my SGS3 rooted and get the same message here. Guess it is a wrong kernel but maybe you have an idea! Thanks!

Comment: I didn't find a solution, I've updated to a newer android and it was fixed.

Comment: Weird. I use CyanogenMod with Nightleys and still have that error message. Well, who knows what this might be. Thanks anyway!

Comment: &^%^&$# Same error message. Also I have CyanogenMod =(

Answer (score 1):

In CyanogenMod  go to setting->apps->select your apps and give permission. In CyanogenMod  you need to give permission even if you given in Android Manifest. May me this is an one of the reason